# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of null

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a login page in react + node + mysql and when I log into my page it is throwing the error -> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of null**.

Even my token is printing using console.log at line 69 of User.js and the res.send is executed but still its giving the error in Profile.js line 37.

Need some help to resolve it.

**Profile.js**

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'

class Profile extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        console.log('profile class')
        this.setState = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
        console.log('value ->' + decoded)
        this.setState({
            first_name: decoded.first_name,
            last_name: decoded.last_name,
            email: decoded.email
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
                    <div className="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
                        <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
                    </div>
                    <table className="table col-md-6 mx-auto">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>First Name</td>
                                <td>{this.state.first_name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Last Name</td>
                                <td>{this.state.last_name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>{this.state.email}</td>       
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Profile
```

**Login.js**

```
import { login } from './UserFunctions'

class Login extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: [e.target.value]})
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        login(user).then(res=> {
            if(res) {
                this.props.history.push(`/profile`)
            }
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                        <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter Email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="password"
                                placeholder="Enter Password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                                Sign in
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

**UserFuctions.js**

```
console.log("abc")
export const register = newUser => {
    return axios
    .post('/users/register', {
        first_name: newUser.first_name,
        last_name: newUser.last_name,
        email: newUser.email,
        password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log("Registered");
    })
}

export const login = user => {
    return axios
    .post('/users/login', {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    })
    .then(res=>{
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

**./routes/Users.js **

```
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors())
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date()

    const userData = {
        first_name: String(req.body.first_name),
        last_name: String(req.body.last_name),
        email: String(req.body.email),
        password: req.body.password,
        created: today
    }
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
         }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(!user){
            bcrypt.hash(String(req.body.password), 10, (err, hash) => {
                userData.password = hash
                console.log('req.body.password -> ' + String(req.body.password))
                console.log('req.body -> '  + req.body)
                console.log('hash -> '    + hash + ' ' + err )
                console.log('keys -> '    + Object.keys(userData))
                console.log('values -> '  + Object.values(userData))
                User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        console.log('inside!')
                        res.json({status: user.email + ' registered'})
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('in catch!' + err)
                        res.send('error: ' + err)
                    })
            })  
        }   else {
            res.json({error: "User already exists"})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('login step 22')
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(user) {
            console.log(req.body.password +  ' >> ' +  user.password)
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(String(req.body.password), user.password)) {
                console.log('bcrypt')
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                    expiresIn: 1440
                })
                console.log('token --> ' + token);
                res.send(token)
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({error: 'User does not exist'})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err})
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial state in `Profile` is incorrect:

```
this.setState = {
   first_name: '',
   last_name: '',
   email: ''
}
```

must be:

```
this.state = {
   first_name: '',
   last_name: '',
   email: ''
}
```

You can actually move it out of the constructor:

```
class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
     first_name: '',
     last_name: '',
     email: ''
  };

  ...
}
```